# Create new object using a function in C# and store it

Tags: c#

I have this program which allows games to be launched from it and the user may add his own game/exe to the program and specify the name and the game's path so it can be launched. This is my code so far without adding the game to the program's settings:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Games_Manager
{
    public class game
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Path;
        public game(string name, string path)
        {
            Name = name;
            Path = path;
        }
    }

    public partial class main_Win : Form
    {
        public main_Win()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void addGame(string gameName, string gamePath)
        {
            //Code to add a game to a list, how can I store the game lists 
            //so the user doesn't have to re-enter games every time 
            //the application runs and rather read the list every time.
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make a function that when called creates a new game object by the name entered and stores the game's name and path. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: the variable name "gameName" conflicts with the parameter name, change one or the other.

Comment: `"This doesn't seem to work"` - The compiler is telling you why it doesn't work.  Did you read the error message?

Comment: `game gameName = new game(gameName, gamePath);` there are two gameName variable name here and both are local

Comment: @David seems that I misunderstood the syntax and I changed the question a bit. I apologise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question. Where are your games stored? If you want to store them in the form then try this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Games_Manager
{
    public class Game
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Path;
        public Game(string name, string path)
        {
            Name = name;
            Path = path;
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWin : Form
    {
        List<Game> games;  //here is where the games will be stored
        public MainWin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            games = new List<Game>(); //here the list is initialized
        }

        public void AddGame(string gameName, string gamePath)
        {
            games.Add(new Game(gameName, gamePath)); //add a game to the list
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I use the standard `C#` [naming convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) for class and variable names. Capitalized for classes and lowercase for variables.

### Edit 1

Here is some very basic code in order to persist the list of games in an `Xml` file. It is requirements that `Game` has a parameterless constructor and it has read/write properties for the name, path etc.

```
    private bool ReadGamesList(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {                
            XmlSerializer xml=new XmlSerializer(typeof(Game[]));
            var fs=File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
            games=new List<Game>((Game[])xml.Deserialize(fs));
            fs.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool SaveGamesList(string path)
    {
        if (games.Count==0) return false;
        XmlSerializer xml=new XmlSerializer(typeof(Game[]));
        var fs=File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        xml.Serialize(fs, games.ToArray());
        fs.Close();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If I store the games in a list, will the list's content be kept when the application exits and relaunches again so the user shouldn't have to re-enter games every time the application restarts or should I save the game list to an XML rather?

Comment: I know but the original question didn't mention anything about persistence. I would save the list in an `XML` file using `XmlSerializer` for the list.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that I misunderstood you.
You create your game with a constructor, like:

```
var g = new game("packman", "c:\folder\packman.exe");
```

If you want to have a factory method, you make it static and call a constructor from there like:

```
var g = game.Create("packman", "c:\folder\packman.exe");
```

Comment: Your answer seems to have solved the problem I had when I misunderstood the syntax, but what I think my real question was is how I can create a new game entry at runtime and then store it to a list of some sort that would save upon exit and then be read again the next time the application is launched. Thanks for the answer thought.